# Visual Studio 2012 Windows Store appmanifest.xml designer missing items

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am creating a windows store app using Visual Studio 2012 Premium.  When I open the Package.appxmanifest to set things like the toast capability of the app, the notifications settings section in the Application UI tab is missing.

On my other machine with the same project in the same version of visual studio, the notification settings appear correctly in the designer.

I have tried uninstalling / reinstalling VS2012 and also the Windows 8 SDK.  Still exactly the same.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

I should also mention that I think this is some sort of tooling issue as if I create a new blank windows store app I have the same problem.

Comment: Have you done a fresh pull from your repository?

Comment: Just tried that and no difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you do a fresh pull to your other working computer in a new location and see if the working computer and do a diff just to make sure you have the same thing in both places?

Comment: Tried a diff on the appxmanifest file and the sln file and they indeed idential

Comment: That's all I've got.  Good luck!

Comment: I have just found this [link](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/12/01/scaled-dpi-aware-image-assets-for-windows-8-apps-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1) and it appears that the manifest has changed as of VS Update 1.  No mention of where the notifications have gone though :(  At least I know why it has changed though.